# Call external json and display in html ajax

Tags: javascript

I have seen many examples but they all have work local json.I have json like this

```
[["02","03"],["12","13"],["22","23"],["32","33"]]
```

[image: Screenshot-2019-01-14-Screenshot.png]

I call json.

```
var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ourRequest.open('GET', 'http://olayufku.info/zoka.json');

  ourRequest.onload = function() {
    var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
    console.log(ourData[1]);
    };
    ourRequest.send();
```

How can I display all data in html ? It's does not matter jquery,javascript etc.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Like 'CORS'?

Comment: Yes but i fixed.So "console.log(ourData[1]);" I can see the data

Comment: So what do you get now? What's happening to the request - check the network tab

Comment: "How can I display all data " means what?

Comment: I just need working example.

Comment: `body.innerHTML = ourRequest.responseText`

Comment: I need 2 columun for 2 variable.

Answer (score -1):

You can add this snippet after your data arrives:

```
const container = document.createElement(‘pre’);
container.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(ourData, null, 2);
document.body.appendChild(container);
```